# D-Link DGS-1500-28P resets to default IP on its own

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I'm not sure if anyone has any experience with this switch specifically, or if they may have had this issue with other d-link devices, but I have a D-link DGS1500 POE switch that will, what seems at random intervals, reset to its default IP address.

I cannot locate any settings within it's configuration interface that would cause it to do this, nor can I find anything in any search criteria. so I was hoping that someone may have had the same issue in the past.

Firmware version: 2.10.002

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue on DSG-1500-28 with Firmware Version 2.50.008. As we have about 10 Switches of this type it is only on one Switch that resets. This switch is the central Datacenter Switch with some LACP Config but nothing special.

We do not just have a IP-Config reset but a full factory reset - LACP Config is also missing.

We reconfigure this switch now, if it happens again we will replace it.